# Write Back Form in OBIEE

Tags: xml, dashboard, obiee

I created a write back form that incorporates an XML template.  Can somebody please let me know what is wrong with my code?  All the write back features have been enabled so I believe my syntax in the form is not valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<WebMessageTables xmlns:sawm="com.siebel.analytics.web/message/v1">
<WebMessageTable lang="en-us" system="WriteBack" table="Messages">
   <WebMessage name="wb_stg_de_accounts_receivable">
      <XML>
         <writeBack connectionPool="LCS_CP_VAR">
            <insert> </insert>
            <update>UPDATE STG_DE_ACCOUNTS_RECEIVABLE SET AL_CUR_RCVBL=@2, MCAREA_90_RCVBL=@3 WHERE ENTITY_ID=@1</update>
         </writeBack>
      </XML>
   </WebMessage>
</WebMessageTable>
</WebMessageTables>
```

Comment: Are there any errors or log messages you could share?

Comment: nope not really, just a generic "Write Back Error" message-

The system is unable to read the Write Back Template 'wb_stg_accounts_receivable'. Please contact your system administrator.

Comment: The system is unable to read the Write Back Template `wb_stg_accounts_receivable` or `wb_stg_de_accounts_receivable`? Those seem different to me and you don't mention the first one in your code unless it is misspelled.

Comment: Duh!? Thank you it has been changed now to wb_stg_de_accounts_receivable.  So new error message-"An error occurred while writing to the server. Please check to make sure you have entered appropriate values. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator."

Comment: Im entering in numbers and the column properties in my admin tool are set to double and in the actual db they are numbers

Comment: What is set in the Write Back properties dialog box of the Admin tool for the connection pool you are using? If you could upload a screenshot of those properties of list them out that would help. Glad could solve one error!

Comment: possible duplicate of [OBIEE 11G writeback Insert XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173656/obiee-11g-writeback-insert-xml)

Answer (score 0):

1. Step 1: Enable Write Back. Add the LightWriteback tag within the serverinstance tag of the instanceconfig.xml file.

   - File path: `$ORACLE_INSTANCE/config/OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent/coreapplication_obips1`
   - Add the following tag: `<LightWriteback>true</LightWriteback>`
   - Restart OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent

     2. Step2: Add WriteBack privileges to the user/Group/Role you are using.
     3. Step3:WriteBack Template.
   - Identify the colums that are to be referenced. we can use the colum position or by colum id as you see them in the XML definition.
   - You must include both insert and update statements in the template.
   - It is the best practice to include the commit statement: `<postUpdate>COMMIT</postUpdate>`.
   - The template should be located here: `$ORACLE_INSTANCE/bifoundation/OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent/coreapplication_obips1/analyticsRes/customMessages`

Once you are done with all writeback settings, you need to set 'Enable Write Back' feature located on Column Properties of the field, from the criteria tab.

This link shows an example XML writeback file: http://obieetutorialguide.blogspot.com/2015/04/write-back-setting-in-obiee-11g.html